# Varying angle between vectors in three js

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, three.js

I've got a problem with three.js. I drawed a three-dimensions vector and all of these three lines (red, blue, green) should be perpendicular but when I'm moving a camera, the angle between k and H vector changes a lot.

[Here it's the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUOsS.png)

Watch the recording and don't worry about lags. The recorder is crappy. Look
at the angle between k and H vectors. It changes a lot when I'm moving and I don't know where is the problem.
It's my camera setup:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1, 10000000);
```

gif:
http://g.recordit.co/EPxfQpjos4.gif

Comment: I don't see the problem at all.... isn't that what is supposed to happen? Could you explain what you mean by they must all be perpendicular because they are perpendicular, in 3D space at least. They just aren't when projected onto a 2D plane.

Comment: When I am moving a camera the angle between E and k vectors is changing a lot. It's not looking natural.

Comment: Looks totally natural to me at least, I have played a lot of video games so maybe my brain is more used to seeing 3D objects - so trust me, nothing is wrong here.